# Truncated expectation = 0 implies function vanishes a.e.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a positive random variable and $ A \subset \Omega$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X1_{A}) = 0$. Show $ X = 0 $ a.e. on $A$.

This basic problem has really stump me. If we define the event $A' = \{\omega \in A : X(\omega) \neq 0 \}$, then we are asked to demonstrate that $\mathbb{E}( 1_{A'}) = 0 $. I've tried various decompositions of the indicator $ 1_{A'}$ and considered many candidate random variables of the form $X1_B$ where $ B \subset A$ such that $ 1_{A'} \leq X1_B$, so that I can leverage monotonicity of expectation. I've also tried creating various $\epsilon$ spaces for a limiting approach. I feel I'm overlooking something very trivial ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An intermediate step makes things easier...

For every positive $n$, let $A_n=[nX\geqslant1]$, then $nX\geqslant\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ hence $0=nE(X)\geqslant P(A_n)\geqslant0$, which shows that $P(A_n)=0$ for every positive integer $n$. Now, $A'=[X\ne0]$ is $A'=\bigcup\limits_{n\geqslant1}A_n$ hence $P(A')=0$.